# Кнопка, которую нужно "тянуть" по горизонтали.

Tags: android

У меня гелакси эйс. Когда я только купила этот смартфон(пол года назад), чтобы ответить на звонок, необходимо было тянуть кнопку "ответить на звонок" по горизонтали вправо. А если я не хочу брать трубку, то нужно было потянуть кнопку "сбросить вызов" по горизонтали влево. Вот хочу реализовать такую кнопку. Какие есть идеи на этот счёт?

Вот у меня мысль: переопределить метод OnTouchEvent у кнопки так, чтобы он контролировал, что кнопку "тянут", т.е. говорил, что координаты меняются по икс. Какие идеи у вас? Буду рада более умным мыслям, особенно, подкреплённым опытом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону [Gesture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html), надо определить жест и потом привязывать к нему некое программное действие.

P.S. Мне тоже очень нравится этот жест в Samsung'ах

Comment: ок, посмотрю)